# how do i set text alignment line by line in single textview

Tags: android

Thanks in advance...

i have a string array which i want to set in textview in proper alignment..
my textview is created dynamically..

my string is :

```
                  private String[] mDialogue = 
                  {
                            "Copa de Agua      8 Oz\n"+
            "Copa de Vino Tinto      6 Oz\n"+
            "Copa de Vino Blanco      5 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Flauta      5 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Tulipan      6 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Cocktail      5 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Sour      5 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Borgo–a      10 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Licor      2 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Sherry      3 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Balon/Cognac      9-25 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Champagne      5 Oz\n"+
            "Copa Catavinos      3 Oz\n"+
            "Vaso High Ball      8 Oz\n"+
            "Vaso On the Rocks      6 Oz\n"+
            "Vaso Collins/Tubo      10 Oz\n"+
            "Vaso Pilsen      10 Oz\n"+
            "Jarra de Cerveza      12 Oz",

            "1 Mililitro         0,001 L\n"+
            "1 Centilitro        0,01 L\n"+
            "1 Decilitro      0,1 L\n"+
            "2 Cucharadas      10 cc\n"+
            "20 Cucharadas      10 cl\n"+
            "1 Taza      236,5 cc\n"+
            "1 Taza      23,6 cl\n"+
            "1 Golpe      1 gota\n"+
            "1 Chorro      10 gotas",
                  }
```

i set this string statically but for different layouts it doesn`t work properly..
when i run in my emulator its look like :i added screen shot for this..
is there any html format which i set my text in proper alignment..??
or if u have any kind of solution then please help me..[image]

Comment: A made a blog entry on this subject How to have 2 or 3 columns in a list view : http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/02/multi-columns-in-listview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a layout with two textviews on each line. As far as I know there's no good way to do what you want in a single textview.

Answer (score 4):

**Actually**, there are better answers than two textViews next to each other, because, then how would they scroll together?
What you are looking at is the perfect place to implement a list view with a custom List Adapter and custom view that is made up of a

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView id=@+id/left alignWithParentLeft=true/>
   <TextView id=@+id/right alignWithParentRight=true/>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Then your custom adapter would just loop through your data and put your 'key' in @+id/left and your 'value' in @+id/right
There are plenty of great tutorials on custom list adapters, and this is a great problem to learn for.

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx
or more in depth, but not necessarily better
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score -1):

absolute layout , that will help to set any where at x and y position